# Mapstruct is not generating implementation for one of my mapper interfaces. Is there a way to know the reason?

Tags: mapstruct

I am using mapstruct to map from/to domain objects to DTO
I have more than 20 mappers that are properly being generated.

One of my mappers is no longer being generated, but compilation is successful.
I use maven and i turned on `showWarnings` flag in the `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration, however i see no warnings regarding that specific mapper (I do see warnings for other mappers).

Is there a way to get some information from the annotation processor regarding mappers that are not being generated?

My mapper interface (with name changes):

```
@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {
    PersonMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PersonMapper.class);

    PersonDTO map(Person entity);

    Person map(PersonDTO dto);
}
```

My Maven configuration:

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
  <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      <annotationProcessorPaths>
        ...
        <path>
          <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
          <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
        </path>
      </annotationProcessorPaths>
      <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do basic tracing (verbose mode) in the upcoming version of MapStruct. Checkout the [documentation](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/blob/master/documentation/src/main/asciidoc/chapter-2-set-up.asciidoc). You can try to use the latest MapStruct master in your project and see if it gives info on why this is not working.

Comment: Tried to use it with v1.3.0.Final - it logs nothing about unimplemented mappers

Comment: does the mapper show up at all (just like the other mappers)?

Comment: The mapper interface name is not present in the logs t all, unlike other mappers

Comment: There must be something different what you do with this one. Is the mapper in the correct package? It's the class name matching the file name?

Comment: Yes, the mapper is perfect. In fact, I know what causes the problem, and it relates to the mapped POJO, however I expect to  have a way to debug such problems rather than guessing and trying (which was how I found the cause)

Comment: ok. It would be good to know if MapStruct could have detected your problem (if annotation processing is somehow not triggered for this class we can't detect it). So if the logging needs to be extended please raise an issue and provide us with the details what goes wrong in this case. I hope my answer provided you with a way to enable logging (which was your question)..

Comment: What was your issue though? Same here some mapper stopped being generated no clue why

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a dependency issue.

My Projet A, had a dependency to another jar B, which contained the object from my mapper method.
That dependency B had a dependency C offering mapstruct mapper for many of the attribut of the object.

Somehow in my project A i was overriding explicitly the version of dependency C to an older version.
So it means that some of the Obj attribute from current B version where not matching with the older C mapper.
Mapstruct said nothing, just stopped generating the impl.

Not sure if this is very clear ... But check your dependencies.